# как удалить из списка с масивов строк?

Tags: c#, list

помогите пожалуйста!
У меня есть список:

```
List<string[]> Data = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] {"nol", "odin", "dva", "tri", " four"},
    new string[] {"nol", "odin", "dva", "tri", " four"},
    new string[] {"nol", "odin", "dva", "tri", " four"}
};
```

и массив индексов которые надо удалить он может быть разной длины

```
int[] removesindex = {1, 3, 4};
```

то есть я хочу получить такой список

```
List<string[]> newData = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] {"nol", "dva"},
    new string[] {"nol", "dva"},
    new string[] {"nol", "dva"}
};
```

я могу получить наоборот индексы которые надо оставить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; ++i)
    Data[i] = Data[i].Where((x, idx) => !removesindex.Contains(idx)).ToArray();
```

Ну или так, если допустимо создавать другой список:

```
Data = Data.Select(a => a.Where((x, idx) => !removesindex.Contains(idx)).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: Хоспади сколько времени я потратил на попытки придумать это(((, я не знал, что через люмбду второй параметр означает индекс, спасибо большое!

Comment: есть один минус если мне надо удалить 0 удалится и элемент с индексом 10, 20 и тд @Андрей

Comment: Эээ, с чего вы взяли? Можно контрпример?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я ошибся - все работает как надо